# A script that counts days since a fixed date

Tags: shell, date

What I need is a script (best would be shell) that counts the number of days which have passed since a fixed date — let's say 8/16/2014.
I thought I could use the

```
 date +%j
```

command and just subtract 229 since August 16 is the 229 day of this year.
Yet, this script would be rendered useless come January 1…

I'm utterly lost since I don't know the first thing about scripting but I thought someone might help.

Comment: Are there any constraints on the reference date?  Must it always be in the past?  Within the last year?  Part of the same year (probably not since you mention the 1st January rollover)?

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU `date` and your fixed date is 2014-08-16, you can use:

```
$ old=$(date +'%s' -d '2014-08-16')
$ new=$(date +'%s')
$ echo $(( ($new - $old) / 86400 ))
9
$
```

---

[Qualcuno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/192024/qualcuno) points out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25495171/a-script-that-counts-days-since-a-fixed-date/25495323?noredirect=1#comment39815867_25495323) that not all days have 86400 seconds in them.

That is correct; most days have 86400 seconds, but some have 90000 and some have 82800 seconds (when you gain or lose an hour because of a switch between daylight saving and standard time).  The long days don't cause a problem; the short ones do. I would prefer a utility that provided 'date (in days)' calculations instead of 'time (in seconds)' calculations for these, but I don't know of a standard Unix utility that does that.

However, we can force `date` to handle it by ensuring that the earlier date works with midnight as the (implicit) time, and the later date works with an explicit time at least one hour after midnight.  With rare exceptions (such as when a country moved across the International Date Line a few years ago — and I'm not going to try to deal with that!), there is at most one net time zone switch of an hour between two dates.  Suppose two dates were three years apart.  For the middle two years, there was a switch to and a switch from standard time, with a net result of zero; there is at most one switch that matters.  This leads to a command that might look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Calculate days between two dates using GNU date command
# Allow for time zone switches

arg0=$(basename "$0" .sh)
DATE=/usr/gnu/bin/date

case $# in
1)  old="$1"; new=$($DATE +"%Y-%m-%d");;
2)  old="$1"; new="$2";;
*)  echo "Usage: $arg0 old [new]" >&2; exit 1;;
esac

case "$old" in
[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]) : OK;;
*) echo "$arg0: $old does not match YYYY-mm-dd" >&2; exit 1;;
esac

case "$new" in
[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]) : OK;;
*) echo "$arg0: $new does not match YYYY-mm-dd" >&2; exit 1;;
esac

if [[ "$old" > "$new" ]]
then t="$old"; old="$new"; new="$t"
fi

# Faulty
old_secs=$($DATE +'%s' -d "$old")
new_secs=$($DATE +'%s' -d "$new")
echo $(( ($new_secs - $old_secs) / 86400 ))

# Safe
old_secs=$($DATE +'%s' -d "$old")
new_secs=$($DATE +'%s' -d "$new 12:00:00")
echo $(( ($new_secs - $old_secs) / 86400 ))
```

Sample output (demonstrating the difference):

```
$ bash delta-days.sh 2014-03-01 2014-03-31
29
30
$ bash delta-days.sh 2000-03-01 2014-03-31
5142
5143
$ bash delta-days.sh 2014-03-01 2000-03-31
5083
5083
$
```

Comment: Same comment as above: you must not assume all days are 86,400 seconds long

Comment: True enough — see revised answer.

Comment: There are also "[leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_seconds)", so you can't even assume {82800, 86400, 90000}

Comment: POSIX time ignores leap seconds.  Leap seconds are a non-issue anyway given the method of calculation shown.  I just added 43200 seconds into the mix just to fix things; the number of leap seconds (around 30 IIRC) doesn't count.

Answer (score 0):

In bash shell:

```
then=$(date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d" "2014-8-16" +%s)
now=$(date +%s)
echo $(($now/86400-$then/86400))
```

In the `date` command, option j says you want to show the specified date (instead of trying to set the system date to it); option f is the format of the input date, and the "+" option is the format of the output date. Format `%s` is the number of seconds in the current epoch, i.e., since 1970/1/1 00:00 UTC.

Comment: Not all days are long 86,400 seconds, unless you're in UTC.

Answer (score 0):

If you have just the year and day-of-year numbers to work with, you can use this formula that calculates a day serial number:

```
number = (year-1)/4*(4*365+1) + (year-1)%4*365 + day   # integer arithmetic
```

Use in a shell script like this (comparing to a date last year):

```
$ year=$(date +%Y)
$ day=$(date +%j)
$ now=$((($year-1)/4*1461+($year-1)%4*365+day))
$ then=$(((2013-1)/4*1461+(2013-1)%4*365+230))
$ echo $then $now
735113 735485
$ echo $(($now-$then))
372
```

The formula only knows about common leap years (every four years), and not about years like 1900, 2100, 2200, that are not leap. That is, it could be a day off starting in year 2100.

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty complete DateTime module for perl (install from [CPAN](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime)) that would suit your purpose:

```
perl -MDateTime  -E '
  $base = DateTime->new(year=>2014, month=>8, day=>16); 
  $now = DateTime->today; 
  $next_year = DateTime->new(year=>2015, month=>8, day=>16); 
  say $base->delta_days($now)->in_units("days");
  say $base->delta_days($next_year)->in_units("days");
'
```

```
10
365
```